# How to set default password algorithm to sha512 on Linux?

Tags: password

on AIX, it would be a simple:

```
chsec -f /etc/security/login.cfg -s usw -a pwd_algorithm=ssha512
```

**Question:** But how can we set the default password algorithm to sha512?

**UPDATE**: I think pwd_algorithm doesn't supports ssha512, but it would be better, yes.. tried it on a Linux Desktop:

```
[root@notebook ~]# john --test -format=ssha512
Will run 4 OpenMP threads
Benchmarking: SSHA512, LDAP [32/64 OpenSSL]... (4xOMP) DONE
Many salts: 3450K c/s real, 858307 c/s virtual
Only one salt:  2826K c/s real, 713696 c/s virtual
[root@notebook ~]# 

[root@notebook ~]# john --test -format=bcrypt
Will run 4 OpenMP threads
Benchmarking: bcrypt ("$2a$05", 32 iterations) [Blowfish 32/64 X3]... (4xOMP) DONE
Raw:    1800 c/s real, 455 c/s virtual
[root@notebook ~]#
```

Does this mean ~1800 passwords per second with bcrypt and ~3 000 000 passwords  per seconds with ssha512 on this Desktop? Slower is better.

Comment: Note that plain SHA512 and SSHA512 are *very* bad password hashes. Personally I recommend using bcrypt instead, but if you want something based on SHA512, use [SHA512Crypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)#SHA2-based_scheme).

Comment: Also as an addition for suse users https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000019248

Answer (score 11):

Setup `ENCRYPT_METHOD SHA512` in file **/etc/login.defs**

Also pay attention to **NOTE** mentioned in the same file, just above the `ENCRYPT_METHOD` parameter, which says

> *Note: It is recommended to use a value consistent with the PAM modules*
>   configuration.

So additional modification along with `/etc/login.defs` is to modify `/etc/pam.d/common-password`

> password        [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure
>   sha512

Here, *obscure* was handled by **login.defs** but now obsoluted by **PAM**

Comment: Thanks! But are you sure this works both on SLES and RHEL and DEB-based ones?

Comment: It works on `ubuntu`. Didn't get chance to try on SLES or RHEL. But it should work, IMHO

Comment: [Works on RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Release_Notes/U7/ppc/ar01s03.html) @freaking-good-question

Comment: This only affect group passwords, user passwords is done by pam and subject to pam configuration.

Comment: Not really. Above setting is not only for use password but also for group password.

In file `/etc/login.defs` it is clearly noted that , one must change the `ENCRYPT_METHOD` value in consistent with pam module configuration. See the edited answer now

Comment: @SHW: See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/login.defs.5.html

Comment: According to man page, ENCRYPT_METHOD is applicable to group password as well as to newusers password

Comment: @SHW: What part of man page said that? I only see `Note: This only affect the generation of group passwords. The
           generation of user passwords is done by PAM and subject to the
           PAM configuration. It is recommended to set this variable
           consistently with the PAM configuration.`

Answer (score 5):

Linux use [pam](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam.d) to handle authentication tasks. Setting default password hashing algorithm was done by editing `/etc/pam.d/common-password`:

```
password    [success=1 default=ignore]    pam_unix.so obscure sha256
```

Change to whatever algorithm you wan to use:

```
password    [success=1 default=ignore]    pam_unix.so obscure sha512
```

Now, your default password hashing algorithm changed to sha512. You also need to force others user to update their passwords:

```
chage -d 0 <username>
```